# How can I bring in color from page to another page

Tags: java, android

I have two pages

The first page has the textview
And other page have textview but with color and there is also a button
................
When the program starts on page 2

I want when the user presses the button brings the color of textview and sends the first page

Then moves on the first page

Then there receives color and puts it in textview that on the front page

I tried it but it did not work what is the solution?

page2

```
public void send(View z)
    {
     Intent sentcolor = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,MainActivity.class);
        sentcolor.putExtra("sendcolor",textView2.getTextColors());
        startActivity(sentcolor);
    }
```

page 1

```
@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("select options");
        menu.add(1,103,1,"change color");


@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        if(item.getItemId() == 103) {
            Intent sent3 = getIntent();
            String colornumber = sent3.getStringExtra("sendcolor");
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(""+colornumber));
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is so many ways to do it ...

1.Its just to use Put Extra like this :

```
 **One Activity**
```

> ```
> String Min=MinPrice.getText().toString(); 
> String Max=MaxPrice.getText().toString(); 
>
> Intent CarByPrice=new Intent(CarByPricesTakePrices.this,CarSearchByPrice.class); 
> CarByPrice.putExtra("Min",Min); 
> CarByPrice.putExtra("Max",Max); 
>
> startActivity(CarByPrice); 
>
>
>  **Second Activity** 
>
> Bundle GetExtra = getIntent().getExtras(); 
> if(GetExtra==null){ 
> return; 
> }else{ 
> String minPrice = GetExtra.getString("Min"); 
> String maxPrice = GetExtra.getString("Max"); 
> }
> ```

2.Its just to use Application class .

3.Use static variable .

Comment: Can you create an example of colors?

Comment: Color is an integer .. just pass it like string and cast it , but why you are not using colors resourse to save all your colors